# Powershell Perfomance with Where-Object?

Tags: performance, powershell

See below code, the only difference in the two scripts is the lack of a script block in the second one, and there is a significant % performance increase due to it.

Is there a reason for this? Is one more native to powershell than the other?

I am doing a large number of scripts with multiple similar blocks in many of them, and would like a reasonable answer as to how to gain easy performance boosts such as this one, so why does the exclusion of a scriptblock in the `Where-Object` (alias `?`) suddenly cut performance by a decent margin?

```
PS C:\Scripts> $a = 1..15 | % {
    Measure-Command {
        $G = Get-ADGroup -Filter *
        1..3 | % {
            $G | ? {$_.Name -eq "TestGroup$($_)"}
        }
    }
}

$b = 1..15 | % {
    Measure-Command {
        $G = Get-ADGroup -Filter *
        1..3 | % {
            $G | ? Name -eq "TestGroup$($_)"
        }
    }
}

($a.TotalMilliseconds | Measure -Average).Average
($b.TotalMilliseconds | Measure -Average).Average

283.479413333333
212.57384
```

Comment: Actually, the difference is much bigger. To isolate it, move `$G` assignment out of the measurement, and use a bigger inner loop like `1..1e5`.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but rather to avoid confusion: it does not _"cut performance"_. It either "cuts run time" or "increases performance". Pick one. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell 3.0 introduced `Where-Object` (aliases: `Where`, `?`) that can check properties directly without a scriptblock.

When a scriptblock is executed PowerShell, like any other language, creates a new execution context and it's very expensive in an interpreted language.

The only reasons to use the old notation with a scriptblock are:

- to have a PS1/PS2-compatible code;
- to perform complex checks;
- to do something besides the check itself.

As for your code, both snippets use scriptblocks in other places, pipelining (it's 5-10x slower than `foreach` statement), and needlessly measure `Get-ADGroup` time, so we can optimize it even more:

```
$group = Get-ADGroup -Filter *
$c = foreach ($i in 1..15) {
    Measure-Command {
        foreach ($j in 1..3) {
            $filtered = foreach ($g in $group) { if ($g.Name -eq "TestGroup$($j)") { $g } }
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes a much bigger gain can be achieved by preparing the data. For example, if some array of objects is repeatedly checked in a loop to see whether it has a certain property value, it's better to convert the array into a hashtable with a key based on that property value:

```
# index by somefield
$lookup = @{}
foreach ($element in $array) { $lookup[$element.somefield] = $element }

# use the indexed lookup table
foreach ($element in $anotherarray) {
    $existingElement = $lookup[$element.somefield]
    if ($existingElement) {
        # do something 
    }
}
```